# Writing public key and private key to files for Lattice based cryptography in Rust

Tags: rust, key-pair

The details of my problem is that I am not really sure how I can go about writing what I need to a couple .bin files. I am fairly new to rust and I wanted to explore quantum resistant lattice based cryptography/encryption using public and private key-pairs. This would also allow me to get more familiar with rust.

I am using the "NTRU" crate. (idk of any other better crates at this time. If you do then let me know) The issue is that the keypair and the data in "kp" in the code below that gets generated can't just normally be written to a file the normal way.

Here is the code that I have for context:

```rust
extern crate ntru;
extern crate hex;

use ntru::rand::RNG_DEVURANDOM;
use ntru::encparams::DEFAULT_PARAMS_256_BITS;
use hex::{encode, decode};
use std::io;
use std::process::Command;
use std::env::consts::OS;





fn clear() {
    match OS {
        "linux" | "macos" => {
            let _ = Command::new("clear").status();
        }
        "windows" => {
            let _ = Command::new("cmd")
                .args(&["/C", "cls"])
                .status();
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}



fn main() {
    let rand_ctx = ntru::rand::init(&RNG_DEVURANDOM).unwrap();
    let kp = ntru::generate_key_pair(&DEFAULT_PARAMS_256_BITS, &rand_ctx).unwrap();
    // println!("{:?}", kp.get_public());
    // println!("{:?}", kp.get_private());

    
    // Save public key from "kp" to file here.
    // Save keypair "kp" to file here

    // Load pub key from file here


    let mut input = String::new();
    clear();
    println!("Enter a message to encrypt: ");
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    let msg = input.trim().as_bytes();


    // Ask for what public key to use to encrypt data. (Should be able to use other public keys.)
    let encrypted_msg = ntru::encrypt(msg, kp.get_public(), &DEFAULT_PARAMS_256_BITS, &rand_ctx).unwrap();
    let encrypted_msg_hex = encode(&encrypted_msg);




    // Get keypair "kp" or private key from file here


    let encrypted_msg_unhex = decode(&encrypted_msg_hex).unwrap();
    let decrypted_msg = ntru::decrypt(&encrypted_msg_unhex, &kp, &DEFAULT_PARAMS_256_BITS).unwrap();



    // Verify that decrypted message matches original message.
    let msg_as_string = String::from_utf8_lossy(msg);
    let dcr_msg = String::from_utf8_lossy(&decrypted_msg);
    assert_eq!(msg_as_string, dcr_msg, "Error: Decrypted message doesn't match original message");

    println!("Original Message: {}\n", msg_as_string);
    println!("Encrypted Message: {}\n", encrypted_msg_hex);
    println!("Decrypted Message: {}", dcr_msg);
}
```

And here are my dependencies:

```ini
[dependencies]
ntru = "0.5.6"
hex = "0.4.3"
```

I have tried to mess around with `serde` and `bincode` but I just am not fully able to understand/wrap my head around how to use the crate(s) yet and the documentation for them isn't really giving me the kick I need to be able to really understand how I am supposed to use them correctly. (Maybe I can get some examples/help here to give me that extra kick I need.) Also, I am not entirely sure if they are even the correct way to store this kind of data to some files to begin with.

The comments in my code basically show you what I want to do and where to save to files and load from files. I am in the most basic terms possible. Looking for a way to correctly save the public key in "kp" to a file and "kp" itself to another file that would be the private file. So I can also use other public keys made with `ntru` to encrypt messages.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

If anyone has any questions or need me to clear up some things, then by all means let me know and I'll try to answer the best I can when I am able to.

Comment: Both `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` have `import` and `export` functions that convert between them and an array of bytes. You should be easily to write a key to disk with `std::fs::write("kp.pub", kp.get_public().export(&kp.get_params().unwrap()))` but be careful with read permissions. The fact that `get_public` isn't fallible even though it requires on the `pk_len` from `get_params` to be correct makes me question the quality of this library - this smells like a SEGV in safe rust. Side note: Use [clearscreen](https://docs.rs/clearscreen/latest/clearscreen/) for screen clearing.

Comment: Yea, [here](https://github.com/FrinkGlobal/ntru-rs/issues/8)'s your SEGV. `ntru` also looks unmaintained. I suggest you pick a [different crate](https://lib.rs/search?q=ntru). `pqcrypto-ntru` looks nice? It has serde support, for one thing.

Comment: @Caesar Looking at `pqcrypto-ntru`, it seems to be just for making the keys. (which I like). Is there any documentation I can follow that'd allow me to encrypt a message using those keys? Or is the `pqcrypto-ntru` crate only for making and sharing keys and i'd have to use a different crate for the encryption? If I do need to use a different crate..which crate?

Comment: Hm. I see [this](https://docs.rs/pqcrypto-ntru/latest/pqcrypto_ntru/ntruhps2048509/index.html) for example, which does more than just make keys: It establishes a shared secret (assume the `encapsulate` was run on a different host). That secret can then be used in some symmetric crypto, I'd thought? But now that you mention it, I have no idea how ntru actually works, and why the `ntru` crate also does data encryption/decryption (and what cipher it uses for that - isn't AES already quantum-resistant?) Scary stuff all this. I hope you won't actually rely on this being secure.

Comment: @Caesar I am not relying on what I'm making here to be actually secure. Just to get more familiar with rust and to learn more about asymmetric encryption methods that'd be quantum resistant (using lattices). If I wanted to be actually secure, i'd go with CRYSTALS-Kyber as chosen by [NIST](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/post-quantum-cryptography) for 2022, or wait for them to pick a winner for 2023. And no, I don't think AES is quantum resistant. But yeah, I guess I did technically get a working answer for my question about writing to files. And this is kinda getting off topic...so Thank you!

Comment: I do wish to get something actually working soon that'd use Kyber and AES-GCM to encrypt data. If you'd like to stay in touch and talk more then here is my [Github](https://github.com/therealOri), where you can find some ways on how to contact me/stay in touch. (I don't even know if there is a way to DM each other on here lol)

Comment: There are no DMs here, but there are (public) [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). If we post too many comments, the system may even auto-create a new one and forbid more comments. (But maybe you need more points to use it. Not sure.)